# HTML5 tags and role for both desktop and mobile navigation

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I'm organizing my webpage for best semantic and accessibility practice. I have the desktop navigation and the mobile navigation. Is it semantically okay to have two navigation tags with its role?

This is my structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="{S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}" lang="{S_USER_LANG}">
<head>
</head>
<body class="section-{SCRIPT_NAME} {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}">

<section class="social-top">
<a title="Twitter" data-original-title="" href="#6"></a>
<a title="Twitter" data-original-title="" href="#6"></a>
<a title="Twitter" data-original-title="" href="#6"></a>
</section>

<header class="header" role="banner"> 
<!-- Header block -->


<nav class="mainnav" role="navigation">

<!-- Main navigation block for Desktop view -->

</nav>


<nav class="mainnav-mob" role="navigation"> 

<!-- MOBILE Navigation content block --> 

</nav>

</header>

<div id="page-body">
<main role="main">


<!-- site content --> 

</main>
</div>

<footer role="contentinfo"> 
<!-- Footer block -->
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is semantically OK to use the navigation role twice. However to differentiate between the element perhaps use `aria-labelledby` as well. See [Using ARIA Landmarks to identify regions of a page](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_landmarks_to_identify_regions_of_a_page#Example_2).

If the navigation is the same consider using a plugin such as [Responsive Nav](http://responsive-nav.com/) so the information is not unnecessarily repeated.